# How to remove array key in php

Tags: php

**Input:**

```
Array
(

    [0] = Array
        (
            [friendId] =107
        )

    [1] = Array
        (
            [friendId] =103
        )

    [2] = Array
        (
            [friendId] =131
        )
)
```

**Expected output:**

```
Array
(

    [0] = 107

    [1] = 103

    [2] = 131

)
```

can you please help me

Comment: Use implode method to remove array..

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php. Job is done

Comment: i have getting this fatal error

Comment: $friendId = array_column($allfriendIds, 'friendId');

Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column() in model.php

Answer (score 3):

You can use **array_column** (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) as follows:

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'friendId' => 107,
    ),
    array(
        'friendId' => 103,
    ),
    array(
        'friendId' => 131,
    )
);

$friendId = array_column($records, 'friendId');
print_r($friendId );
```

Comment: i have tried but getting  fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column()

Comment: What version of php are you using? @g.v.v.phaniGuduri

Comment: php version 5.3.10

Comment: This function is available since version 5.5.0.  @g.v.v.phaniGuduri

Comment: ok thanks i will try other alternatives

Answer (score 1):

**try once**

```
function myfunction($v) {
    return($v['friendId']); 
}

$a = array(
    array('friendId' => 107),
    array('friendId' => 103),
    array('friendId' => 131)
);
print_r(array_map("myfunction",$a));
```